# creating a new module in a chosen library using libreoffice basic

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

How can I create a new module in a chosen library using libreoffice basic code?

I've tried:
ThisComponent.getLibraryContainer().getByName("C_calc").getModuleContainer().insertByName("newModule", "")
with no effect. It throws an exception:

Type:com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: types do not match at ./basic/source/basmgr/basmgr.cxx:1738.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[XStarBasicAccess](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1script_1_1XStarBasicAccess.html)::getLibraryContainer() is deprecated. Use [BasicLibraries](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03131900.html?DbPAR=BASIC) instead.

```vb
oLibs = BasicLibraries
oLib = oLibs.getByName("C_calc")
oLib.insertByName("newModule", "REM hello")
```